# WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile

Tags: docker

When running `docker info` I'm seeing this warning.

> WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile

How can I change the profile of the docker daemon back to seccomp?

Comment: did my answer solve your doubts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/):

> Secure computing mode (seccomp) is a Linux kernel feature. You can use
> it to restrict the actions available within the container. The
> seccomp() system call operates on the seccomp state of the calling
> process. You can use this feature to restrict your application's
> access.

You can review the seccomp profile that has been applied by running:

```
docker info --format '{{ .SecurityOptions }}'
```

You can choose to apply a custom `seccomp` profile to the daemon level, by using the `--seccomp-profile` flag at daemon, such as:

```
dockerd --seccomp-profile <path_to_seccomp_profile>
```

The default json profile can be found here https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json

So, in your case, you should download the default profile and then set it with
the `dockerd --seccomp-profile` option.